# tufte-book: I can't display a figure in lanscape properly

Tags: geometry, tufte, pdflscape, lscape

I need to display a figure in landscape mode in a tufte-book latex document.

Yet, I cannot display it properly. It seems the margin is placed below. For e.g., try

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{landscape}
    \lipsum
    \begin{figure*}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[]{example-image}
        \caption{Test.}
    \end{figure*}
    \lipsum
\end{landscape}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

If I use `figure` instead of `figure*`, the rending is better, but that's not that either.

Another problem: how to make showframe be landscape ?

I'd like to perform some geometry modification like this, but it does not work either.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\lipsum

\newgeometry{asymmetric,
   a4paper, 
   left=24.8mm, top=27.4mm, 
   headsep=2\baselineskip,
   textwidth=49\baselineskip, marginparsep=8.2mm, marginparwidth=49.4mm, 
   textheight=107mm, headheight=\baselineskip}
\begin{landscape}
    \lipsum
    \begin{figure*}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Test.}
    \end{figure*}
    \lipsum
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Does someone has a solution, please ?

Comment: Hi! You seem to be asking two questions, here. On TeX.SX, we try to keep unrelated questions on separate pages. If you have multiple questions that are unrelated to one another, you should ask each in a separate TeX.SX "question". You'll stand a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer to each of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it.

First, I agree that's not the current question but you can't trust `showframe`when using `pdflscape`.

Second, I used:

- `afterpage` to wait for a new page before asking for a landscape figure (otherwise, it cuts the text),
- `newgeometry` to modify the lengths for the margin,
- `pdflscape` to rotate the figure.

Final MWE is:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{environ}

\def\mylandscapebody#1{%
    \afterpage{%%
        \newgeometry{
            asymmetric,
            a4paper,
            left=24.8mm, top=27.4mm, 
            headsep=2\baselineskip,
            textwidth=156.4mm, % 107mm + 49.4mm
            textheight=183.5mm, % 49\baselineskip (241.1mm) - 49.4mm 
            marginparsep=8.2mm, marginparwidth=49.4mm, 
            headheight=\baselineskip}
        \begin{landscape}
            \thispagestyle{empty} %% Remove header and footer.
            #1%
        \end{landscape}
        \restoregeometry%
    }%
}

\NewEnviron{mylandscape}{%%
    \expandafter\mylandscapebody\expandafter{\BODY}%%
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{mylandscape}
    \begin{figure*}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Test.}
    \end{figure*}
    Bla Bla \dotfill \marginpar{test \dotfill}
\end{mylandscape}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Two remaining problems:

1. I should fine-tune the geometry lengths, especially I do not know exactly what `pdflscape` does.
2. It seems I cannot put `\par` inside `mylandscape`,
3. I fastly tested it, but it seems the margin is not asymetric.
4. As the landscape page is produced just after a page has been output, beware that the figure 1.5 is not before the 1.4 figure :s

The two last problems are not for me as I just want to display a figure. But I should be aware of problem #4.